# JFrame.repaint() stops getting called in a Java Canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, paint

**EDIT: Problem solved, turns out I needed to call main.repaint() instead of frame.repaint()**

I am using a class that **extends Canvas** and **overrides** the '**paint(Graphics graphics)**' method. In a loop which **activates 60 times a second** (it works like it's supposed to), I have called **frame.repaint()** (the canvas is correctly added to the frame). The paint method gets called about **4 or 5 times**, then stops getting called. My other method in the loop, **does not stop however**, proving that it's the frame.repaint() method.

***To make the problem clear, the JFrame.repaint() method stops getting called after 4 or 5 attempts within a second.***

To prove this, I've increased an integer every second in my update method (which is getting called 60 times per second) and I'm using that as the **x cordanite** as a rectangle in my frame, which should make the **rectangle larger each second**. The rectangle paint's for 2 seconds or so, then stops growing, however the integer is still increasing. One thing to keep in mind that the rectangle **does draw for the first few times**, indicating that it's some sort of issue with the frame.

---

- **Is there a better way to call the paint(Graphics graphics) method? Do
  I have some flaw in my code?**

---

Sorry if my explanation was confusing, but I **attached the code below** (and in a pastebin file that you can find here: http://pastebin.com/WNnK54gq)

I have been looking for the past few hour's, and **haven't found any replacement** for the frame.repant() method.

Thanks in advanced!

```
public class Main extends Canvas {

//Static Variables
public static Main main;

public static String name = "Game";
public static double version = 1.0;

public static int FPS;

//Object Variables
private JFrame frame;

private boolean running;

private int screenX;
private int screenY;

private int x = 0;

//Constructor
public Main() {
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
}

//Main Method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    main = new Main();

    main.init();
}

//Object Methods
private void init() {
    frame = new JFrame(name);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(main);

    loop();
}

public void loop() {
    running = true;

    int fps = 0;

    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

    final double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60;
    double delta = 0;

    while (running) {

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;

        while (delta >= 1) {

            if (fps <= 60) {
                fps++;

                update();
                frame.repaint();

                delta--;
            }
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;

            log("Running at " + fps + " FPS and UPS");

            FPS = fps;

            fps = 0;

        }
    }

}

public void update() {
    screenX = frame.getWidth();
    screenY = frame.getHeight();

    x++;

    if (x >= 500) x = 0;

    log("update");

    //update gametstate
}

public void log(String string) {
    System.out.println("[" + name + "] [" + version + "] " + string);
}

public void log() {
    System.out.println("[" + name + "] [" + version + "]");
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, screenX, screenY);

    //update gamestate

    graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 200, x, 300);
    log("rendered");
}
```

Comment: Beware of the potential of blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, make sure you are off loading the creation of the UI to the EDT, see [initial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details. Consider starting a dedicated `Thread` to handle the main loop.  `Canvas` is not double buffered, this is going to cause flickering to occur as the component is updated.  Consider using something like `JPanel` and override `paintComponent` instead.  Always call `super.paintXxx`

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (delta >= 1) {

        if (fps <= 60) {
            fps++;

            update();
            frame.repaint();

            delta--;
        }
    }
```

Once fps hits 61, it will stop rendering or updating, because you never set fps back to 0.

```
 while (delta >= 1) {

        if (fps <= 60) {
            fps++;

            update();
            frame.repaint();

            delta--;

            if(fps == 60) fps = 0;
        }
    }
```

You need to set fps back to 0.

Comment: My engine works perfectly, and I even tried your code, but nothing changed. As I said in the post, the other methods get called 60 times per second, like they should. It's an issue with the JFrame.repaint(), so I was wondering if there is a better solution to using that method.

Comment: @user3131055 Thats because i didnt change anything until now. The first block of code in my answer is YOUR code; its the part thats causing the problem. Ive updated my answer with the solution

Comment: Once again, this doesn't change anything. Thank you for your quick response, but as stated in the post, anything called within that loop will get called 60 times a second. The issue is NOT my loop, it's calling the frame.repaint() method...

Comment: @user3131055 I am very sorry, I was answering from my phone, and usually I can spot it from there :s I got on my computer and ran it, your problem is that you call `frame.repaint();` instead of `main.repaint();`. You need to repaint your canvas, since you're handling your graphics on the canvas and not the frame

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I really appreciate you running it and figuring it out, I would of never found this out! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. By the way, I hope you know that when you're calling `graphics.fillRect(x, y, width, height)`, you put variable `x` in the spot width goes